# Do Azure DevOps Service Connection need elevated permissions?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I'm using Azure DevOps services to create service connection but getting errors.
I am trying to follow the steps outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#use-spn)

These are the steps I followed:

- Add a new AAD app registration with secret.
- In DevOps, from project settings create a new service connection.

  - Connection type: ARM
  - Authentication method: Serviceprincipal (manual)
  - Env: Azure Cloud
  - Scope: Subscription
  - Subscription Id: xxx
  - Subscription name: xxx
  - service principal id: xxx
  - service principal key: xxx
  - Tenant Id: xxx

When I click Verify, I get this error:

> Failed to query service connection API:
> 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx?api-version=2016-06-01'.
> Status Code: 'Forbidden', Response from server:
> '{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client 'abc'
> with object id 'abc' does not have authorization to perform action
> 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/read' over scope
> '/subscriptions/xxx' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently
> granted, please refresh your credentials."}}'

So,

Does this mean, my app registration need to have read permission on this xxx subscription?
Can't I scope it to resource group level? If yes, how can I do that as I don't see that option in portal?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

> Does this mean, my app registration needs to have read permission on this xxx subscription? Can't I scope it to resource group level?

Yes, your app registration needs to have **read** permission on that subscription level. You cannot scope it to resource group level as the query https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx?api-version=2016-06-01 is related to **subscriptions**.

Read permission will be included in roles like reader, contributor and owner. For least privilege, I assigned **`reader`** role to the app like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Subscriptions -> Your Subscription -> Access Control(IAM) -> Add role assignment -> Select Role***

[image]

***After assigning that role, verification is successful like below:***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you create ARM service principle (Manual) type Service Connection, you need to manually add role assignment for this service principle inside your Azure Subscription in Azure Portal.

In common, you will need to give this service principle “Contribute” role to perform the action.

Find the Overview Page of this app registration in AAD.

[image]

In your Azure Subscription page, click IAM -> Add -> Add role assignment

[image]

Select the name of this app and assign it a "Contribute" role of this Azure Subscription.

[image]

Comment: Don't you think this is over scoped? I mean earlier I was able to do same with permissions scoped at resource group level but now it should be at subscription level. Even though it is Read-only but still against least-privileged model.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same Error message: The client 'abc' with object id 'abc' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/read' over scope '/subscriptions/xxx' or the scope is invalid.

However the ServicePrincipal did not need permissions to read the subscription!
Adding the Principal as a Contributer to a resource group or a specific Web-App was enough.
Resource Group -> rg-blabla -> Access Control/IAM -> Add role assignment -> Contributer -> select the principal

The error message was somehow misleading.
Probably try that before granting subscription permissions :)